# Fade out grid view when a particular grid view cell is clicked

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, modalviewcontroller

In my app, my root view is a grid view with cells. When I tap a particular cell, the modal view controller will pop up with details of that particular cell.

How can I fade out the grid view when my modal view is present?

Also, how can I dismiss the modal view when I tap anywhere in the grid view, which is behind my modal view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 5 brought in a new UIViewController method, [`presentViewController:animated:completion:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a) (documentation linked for you) and of course you probably already know about [`presentModalViewController:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentModalViewController%3aanimated%3a) (documentation says to use the `presentViewController` method in place of the older `presentModalViewController`, but this depends on if you are supporting iOS 5 & newer only).

You can set animated to YES and use a fade animation, or set the parent view's alpha closer to 0.0 (to "fade" it somewhat).

The `UIView` documentation has some notes about fading things, including some sample code.  Look at [`animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a)

As for dismissing the modal view, wouldn't [`dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissModalViewControllerAnimated%3a) work?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.yeah, dismissmodalviewcontroller will work. But I want to dismiss it when i tap out side the view.

Comment: Embed the view you want to present modally into another view (with a clear color) and then you can detect when taps happen outside your content view (and dismiss it in the process).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please give me a reference to that?